# Where can I find the nominal price of a stock prior a split into multiple companies?

Tags: historical-data, stock-split

Where can I find the nominal price of a stock prior a split into multiple companies?

In my case, I am searching the price of Hewlett Packard before it split into Hewlett Packard Enterprise and HP inc. on 2015-11-05.  On every website I looked for I cannot find the old stock.  I can only find the two newly created stocks, HPQ and HPE with all historical prices listed "adjusted".  I know that the stock trades around $26 USD before the split, but I need the exact amount for income tax purposes.

My question might be a duplicate of [How to find historical stock price for a de-listed or defunct company?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/18723/how-to-find-historical-stock-price-for-a-de-listed-or-defunct-company), but I am asking since the answer could be different as the company is not defunct, but transformed.  Is the old Hewlett Packard considered delisted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo Finance provides the proper closing price.  HP's historical data around the split date can be found [here](https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/HPQ/history?period1=1445400000&period2=1447218000&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d). The open, high and low of the day are wrong prior the split, but the closing price is right and for HP, it was $26.96 USD.  The next day the closing price was $13.83 USD.

Answer (score 0):

When Hewlett Packard split they changed their name to HP Inc. and spun off Hewlett Packard Enterprise as a new corporation. This means HP Inc. has the same stock history and ticker (HPQ) as Hewlett Packard did so that's the one you want to search for. As you noticed this also means it's impossible to search for old Hewlett Packard's stock performance alone.

One free service that seems to show the unadjusted historical stock price of HPQ is Google finance: https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AHPQ

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case with Google's service.  The stock traded around $26 USD before the split.  The data provided by Google is around the split date is $14 USD.

Comment: @HansDeragon Are you sure? I added the image of the price at the stock split ($26.96) according to Google.

Comment: you seam right, but unfortunately, the resolution of the graphic is to coarse to get the price of a specific day.  It shows some form of average across multiple days.  It is not useful for me.  But thanks for pointing it out.  Your input might be valuable to someone else.

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same problem. Just multiply the HPQ share price that you can get from yahoo or any other system with 2.202 in order to get the old share since this was the split ratio.