# Historical stock price of Anadarko Corporation Jan. 8 and May 26, 1983

Tags: stocks, price, historical-data

I am looking for the common stock price of Anadarko Corporation for January 8 and May 26, 1983.
Can anyone help?

Comment: If they still exist, try the microfiche records at a good library.

Comment: Wikipedia says "In 1986, Panhandle Eastern Corporation distributed its interests in Anadarko to its shareholders via a corporate spin-off and Anadarko became a public company." sourced from  The New York Times. August 21, 1986. So there was no Anadarko trading in 1983. Also, January 8 1983 was a Saturday. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find historical stock price for a de-listed or defunct company?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/18723/how-to-find-historical-stock-price-for-a-de-listed-or-defunct-company)

Answer (score 1):

A good library will subscribe to databases that you can access online by logging in with your library card number. One such database is the *ProQuest Historical Newspapers: The Wall Street Journal‎ (1889 - 2002)* database, which will allow you to search and read the entire issue for the dates in question.

In your case, January 8, 1983, was a Saturday, so there was no trading. The Monday, January 10, 1983, issue of the *Wall Street Journal* gives the High/Low/Last trading prices for Friday, January 7, 1983, for shares trading on NASDAQ, AMEX, NYSE exchanges and OTC.

Also, Anadarko Petroleum Corporation did not go public until 1986, so there were no Anadarko shares trading publicly in 1983. Its parent was Panhandle Eastern Corporation. (Source: ["Panhandle Plans Anadarko Spinoff"](https://www.nytimes.com/1986/08/21/business/company-news-panhandle-plans-anadarko-spinoff.html). The New York Times. August 21, 1986.)